# Duplicate modules after Angular2 AotPlugin build in Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I have a Webpack (v 2.1.0-beta.22) build that compiles an Angular2 app with AoT through `@ngtools/webpack`. So far so good, until I inspected the build profile stats, and discovered all the `.ngfactory.ts` are present several times in many chunks.

What's strange, is the `CommonChunksPlugin` was already in place, and in fact I only see those modules duplicated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing very similar problem. I had quite a lot of files in `$$_gendir/src/app` and it seemed to be duplicated with `src/app`.

I managed to get rid of it by setting `skipCodeGeneration: true` parameter in `AotPlugin`.

Comment: No ! skipCodeGeneration: true will simply disable AOT !

Comment: Why on earth is that option just not called 'enableAOT' or at least documented that it will disable AOT -.- stupid angular developers.